# Can multiple elements be used in a hash table?

Tags: java, hashtable, salt

I am trying to create a table that contains the user name, an encrypted pass phrase and a salt. The pass phrase and associated salt are unique to the user name. Would a hash table be a good idea for this setup or should I use a different data structure?

Comment: What are you doing with this table?  A hash table could feasibly store those (you'd probably need a containing value object or similar)

Comment: The question isn't clear, please clarify:

Do you want to (a) create multiple users that each have their own usernames and pass phrases etc or (b) create one user with these attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Go for hashtable, if you want to store elements as key value pair, where keys need to be unique